# Superslim header width match_parent

Tags: android, superslim

I've been reading documentation provided in superslim github.

I want to achieve recyclerview with pinned list items. Not grid.

Can any one give me a sample would really helpful.

Sample provided in github was grid items and headers are wrapped.